# MATLAB and the discrete Fourier transform

Tags: matlab

I have previous experience with MATLAB, but the problem that I face is some problems in applying a problem in (DSP: Digital signal processing) which is not my study field, but I must finish those problems in days to complete my project.

All I want is help with a method and steps of solving this problem in MATLAB and then I can write the code with myself.

The problem is about the signal

x(t) = exp(-a*t);

1) What's the [discrete Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) of the sampled signal with sample rate fs?

2) If a=1 and fs=1, plot the amplitude spectrum of the sampled signal

3) Fix the sampling frequency at fs = 1 (Hz) [**what does it mean**?] and plot the magnitude of the Fourier Transform of the sampled signal at various values of a

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be a straight dump of a homework problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DFT is used to bring a discrete (i.e. sampled) signal from the time domain to the frequency domain. It's an extension of the [Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform). It is used when you are interested in the frequency content of your data. The DFT { x(t) } yields an expression X(F); sample rate (fs) is a term in its expression... This will be your answer to part 1.

You can find tables for the example expression `exp(-a*t)`, but you really should study the electrical engineering (and perhaps math) background for this concept. If you have ability in MATLAB AND you get the basics of the Fourier transform/[discrete Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform), then these problems will be straightforward.

MATLAB actually has a tutorial for this subject matter: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/math/brenr5t-1.html. Good luck...

Comment: thanks, but the tutorial has no enough information or examples.

if you have another tutorials, please provide me with.

Comment: The MathWorks link is broken.